# I don't want the last word of the TextView cut out half

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

I am using TextView together with android:ellipsize=true and android:maxLines=1 attributes because I don't want the last word of the TextView cut out half.

Example

android:textView="I am an honest man".
The result I want is "I am an honest...".

Not "I am an hone...".

What should I need to do to get the result I want?

Comment: Do you want this for specific text? U can use autosize attribute also,

Comment: I want dot(....) in last of text

Comment: set the textview width to match parent. Also make sure the parent has enough space

Answer (score 0):

You need to set width more for the Textview if the width is not enough then will auto cut
and you can follow the below trick I know it is not appropriate but you can achieve the result
make textview with wrap content and set text with Eclipse exp abc.setText("your text...")

Comment: i want that  if word is cut off then  dont show that word and remaining word show\